# Handling the error PInvokeStackImbalance

Tags: c#

I would like to change the state of my checkbox depending on the result of a printing method. If the printer is not connected or cannot be found, I would like to handle it. Right now, if the printer is not found, i.e., it is not connected, my code throws a `PInvokeStackImbalance Occured` and if I press continue, it does not go to my catch(Exception ex) clause. I would like to handle this error either to get to the catch clause or just to capture this `PInvokeStackImbalance` message. Below is my code.

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtPrinterName.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a printer name");
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                var mstrFullCutCode = (char)27 + (char)109;
                _finalLength = noteToPrint;
                var printingObject = new PrintClass.Class1.RawPrinterHelper();
                var result = PrintClass.Class1.RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(txtPrinterName.Text, _finalLength + mstrFullCutCode);
                frmMain.Instance.LblStatus.Text = "Printer is found: " + result;
                if ((bool)result)
                {
                    frmMain.Instance.CbPrinter.Checked = true;
                }
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                frmMain.Instance.LblStatus.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
            }

        }
```

This is the image of **Managed Debugging Assistant**
[image]

Comment: It is not an exception.  An MDA (managed debugging assistant) is extra tooling added to the CLR to tell the debugger that something Really Nasty happened.  The kind of nasty that makes a programmer lose significant clumps of head-hair when it happens and there is no diagnostic for it.  A stack imbalance fits the nasty quite well, it doesn't automatically make a program crash.  Only when you make a seemingly innocent change to the code or a build setting, the worst kind of bug to diagnose.  The only way to "handle" it is to fix the bug, but it probably is not code that you wrote. Throw it away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> … and if I press continue, it does not go to my catch(Exception ex) clause. I would like to handle this error either to get to the catch clause or just to capture this PInvokeStackImbalance message.

I don't think you can.

Although an MDA *looks* like an unhandled exception, it isn't one.  See for example the first note on the page [**Diagnosing Errors with Managed Debugging Assistants**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/diagnosing-errors-with-managed-debugging-assistants) which in part says this (emphasis added) …

> If an MDA event is raised when a debugger is not present, the event message is presented in an unhandled exception dialog box, **although it is not an unhandled exception**.

A `PInvokeStackImbalance` managed debugging assistant (MDA) ["*is activated when the CLR detects that the stack depth after a platform invoke call does not match the expected stack depth*"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/pinvokestackimbalance-mda).  As such it would typically represent an error in the managed signature being used by PInvoke, **not** a missing printer.

You should check your declaration of the native methods you are using - most likely `OpenPrinter`.

If you're using the `RawPrinterHelper` class from [KB article 322091](https://web.archive.org/web/20131208081827/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091) notice that `SendBytesToPrinter` returns `true` or `false` to indicate success or failure but `SendStringToPrinter` ignores that return value and always returns `true`.

The `SendStringToPrinter` function should really return the result of `SendBytesToPrinter` and your code should check that return value and call [`GetLastWin32Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error?view=netframework-4.7.1) to get more information on the failure.  You should be getting an 1801 error code - the printer name is invalid.

Comment: Thank you Frank Boyne. It lead me somewhere.